# How to maintain normal ICS routing after the ICS host connects to a VPN?

Tags: vpn, routing, ics

I have two computers in my home sharing an internet connection. They both have Windows XP and are connected together with a cross-over cable and share the internet connection via Windows ICS.

The problem is that whenever the host machine connects to a VPN service the client machine loses internet connectivity. I understand this happens because establishing a VPN connection on the ICS Host modifies the Routing Table on the ICS Host and forces all clients that try to connect to the Internet to use the VPN routing table instead of the routing table used to connect to the Internet service provider (ISP) and I found this link while Googling for a solution:

http://www.howtonetworking.com/vpn.htm#Do%20not%20install%20VPN%20on%20a%20system%20with%20ICS%20running

It points out how this problem can be fixed but very very briefly. I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to edit my routing table and what should I change so the host machine can continue using its VPN connection while the client machine is using the routing table used to connect to my ISP on the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom post connect action that updates the routing table.

the technet article supporting this idea is here: http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc786865%28WS.10%29.aspx

i don't have a windows box atm so i can't walk through it

if i had to do it command-line windows supports `route add` i think